# How to skip data in a loop?

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, for-loop

I have a problem to skip some data if condition exist

Output from my loop:

```
None
2 of 61
None
None
None
2 of 1,976
2 of 52
2 of 56
2 of 231
2 of 59
None
2 of 250
2 of 138
2 of 367
None
2 of 221
2 of 372
None
2 of 90
None
2 of 208
```

but I wish that my loops prints only first None in a row like: `None, 2 of 61, none, 2of 1,976 and so on :)`

How can I achive it? I tried something with a counter flag but it stil print all "None" values

```
    if comment.string == None:
        flag=+1
        if flag==1:
            countCC = comment.string
        else:
            continue
    else:
        if comment.string.find('of') != -1:
            countC = comment.string.split("of ")
            countCC = int(re.sub("\D", "", countC[1]))
        flag = 0
        try:
            worksheet.write(row, 4, "Komentarzy:")
            worksheet.write(row, 5, countCC)
            row += 1
        except Exception:
            pass
```

Comment: Forgive me, but I cannot tell what your asking. Could you please clarify?

Answer (score 3):

If all you want is to prevent `None` after `None`, simply check the previous item:

```
prev = 'anything but None'
for item in data:
    if item is None and prev is None:
        continue
    print(item)
    prev = item
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use `continue`.

```
if your condition that you want to skip:
    continue
 else:
     normal operation
```

Comment: I updated my code but it stil doesnt work :(

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses a flag that needs to be set to `True` whenever the first `None` element gets found (and printed) so that any subsequent `None` element will get skipped. A non `None` element will reset the flag, so the cycle can repeat. Adapt as necessary.

You can run it on: https://eval.in/639413

```
data = [
None,
'2 of 61',
None,
None,
None,
'2 of 1,976',
'2 of 52',
'2 of 56',
'2 of 231',
'2 of 59',
None,
'2 of 250',
'2 of 138',
'2 of 367',
None,
'2 of 221',
'2 of 372',
None,
'2 of 90',
None,
'2 of 208',
]

# initialize the flag
skip_next_none = False

for item in data:
  # if the current item is None start the checks 
  if item is None:
    # if the flag is set, skip this
    if skip_next_none:
       continue
    # otherwise, set the flag to skip the next   
    skip_next_none = True
  else:
    # we found a non-None element: clear the flag
    skip_next_none = False
  print item
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a 'count' variable to figure out if 'None' has already been printed and only print the first one it encounters before moving on.

If this indeed does what you're asking, it should save you some code. Not using your variables and not necessarily the most pythonic but here's what it does:

- Count starts as set to 0
- Run a for loop against your list: "comment in comments"
- Check if 'comment' is 'None' and if count is < 1
- This will print the first None and iterate up the count
- Then check for the next item that's not 'None' and print it. Keep doing that until it hits another 'None'
- Rinse / repeat :)

  ```
  count = 0
  for comment in comments:
      if comment == None and count < 1:
          print(comment)
          count = 1
      elif comment != None:
          print(comment)
          count = 0
  ```